# Does cashing out 401k interfere in unemployment

Tags: united-states, 401k, unemployment, arizona

If I cash in my 401k do I have to log that as earned income on my weekly unemployment filing in Arizona. I had no choice since $160 per week does not pay my bills. I used it to pay off my car and a credit card to alleviate the financial load.

Comment: Have you already cashed it out?  I would probably have sold the car before paying 50% tax/penalty on a 401(k) cashout.  I would STRONGLY consider trying to make a contribution to avoid the penalties if there's any feasible way to do so.

Comment: Yes, some states reduce unemployment payments when there is 401k income, a quick search suggests that AZ is one of these states.

Comment: @DStanley: for someone unemployed and struggling to make a car payment I doubt the marginal rate is above 25%+state plus the 10% penalty. You can't recontribute to a 401k when you're not earning pay, although you could open or add to an IRA within 60 days and treat it as a rollover.

Comment: I agree with DStanley. Far better to sell the car and use that to make CC payments.  Because your emergency fund was not fully funded, you should not have had a car note, much less credit card load.  Now is the time to take whatever job you can (fast food, delivery, Walmart, etc.), as a bridge job, while you look for a new, full-time, career track job.

Comment: @DStanley Early disbursements are penalized by 10%, and add to your taxable income (another 10-25% of the disbursement).

Comment: @Xalorous Fair enough, so 10% penalty, 15% fed tax and 3% AZ state tax. 28% in taxes in penalties still make it a bad idea except if completely desperate.

Comment: @DStanley I had a 401k loan which (complicated story) became a disbursement and resulted in me owing 2400 in penalties and taxes on roughly 7400 of unrepaid loan.  So for me it was closer to 33%.  So 401k loans may sound good, but one should make sure the repayment period is short and be able to repay on short notice.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your state's unemployment rules.  But it appears that AZ will reduce your employment benefits if you take out money from your 401(k).  The advice in the link is to wait until you have exhausted all of your benefits before drawing on your 401(k).

https://www.justanswer.com/employment-law/7lnb9-arizona-unemployment-laws-i-laid-off-year-downsized.html

However, given the financial hardship you are under, it may make financial sense to clear out sources of high interest debt such as a credit card or car as these could outweigh any benefit you may gain by paying the minimum credit card payment, and pushing back on auto loan payments.  It would also give you some peace of mind.

As the benefits vary based on the amount of your 401(k) withdraw, it is important that you keep the withdraw to the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Under the CARES act there is no penalty and you have three years to pay the federal taxes or to put the money back without penalty.  Just make sure you withdraw with a direct cause relating to the Coronavirus.

Just realized this was an old post not related to the Coronavirus ‍

Comment: Plus it was about the effect on _unemployment insurance_ (aka unemployment benefit), not on taxes. And as stated in past comments and answer, unemployment (in US) is run separately and differently by each state, not federally.